# Our company office website being wrongly filtered/blocked by websense under category "Potentially Damaging Content"

Tags: filtering

Our clients are complaining that they are not able to access our site. We figured out that websense is blocking our site by wrongly categorizing under "Potentially Damaging Content"

We are INKAT Tech Private Ltd. and our website is www.inkattech.com

We are an Information technology products and services provider

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You will have to take this up with the websense folks (which is more or less a futile effort imo). Ideally, you can work with your clients and add an exception to the firewall for your site.

Comment: http://www.inkattech.com/ I would move around even more boxes to finally confuse the users…

Comment: @feeela lol just noticed the boxes moving, kind of looks like the ground hog game at carnivals that you got to hit down with a hammer. I just don't know where to look or click first

Comment: thanks for the feedback.. check now.. we have slowed down the tile movement now. The intention is to emulate the live tiles UI of windows 8

Answer (score 2):

I scanned your website with Sucuri and it came up clean of malware http://www.sucuri.net however it did show a warning:

> **Wordpress internal path:**
>   /home/content/62/8621962/html/inkattech/wp-content/themes/Matrix/index.php

Sucuri is quite good at picking all types of malware and if it says your site is clean of malware it's a safe bet that it is. So I would also contact websense and ask why they filtered you.

Comment: Domain clean by Google Safe Browsing: inkattech.com - reference
Domain clean by Norton Safe Web: inkattech.com - reference
Domain clean on Phish tank: inkattech.com - reference
Domain clean on the Opera browser: inkattech.com - reference
Domain clean by SiteAdvisor: inkattech.com - reference
Domain clean on Sucuri IP/URL malware blacklist: inkattech.com - reference
Domain clean by the Sucuri Malware Labs blacklist: inkattech.com - reference
Domain clean on Yandex (via Sophos): inkattech.com - reference

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, they are right.

Before you jump to the conclusion that they are "wrongly filtering", I would suggest you audit your site to make sure everything really is in order. You should review the generated output of your site as served up not to you but to an anonymous user on the internet (use a proxy server to reach it from something other than your known address and an incognito mode so you don't send the site cookies etc).

It's quite possible your server is infected with some kind of malware that does inject dangerous objects in your site as it is served. It is also possible you just have some programming mistakes that are potentially dangerous. You might not be properly signing a java applet, you might be serving up something cross-domain, you might have a dangerous javascript hack in your code, or any other combination of trigger factors.

Comment: I have tested for malware via sucuri.net and it shows all clean